# can i create a custom radio skill to play radio stations live in alexa

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am new to alexa skill kit. I want to create a skill that play a live audio stream for a radio station.
Is it possible to play live stream in skill. please tell me it is possible or not and if it is possible how can I achieve it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The skill already exists.  Just say, "Alexa, play WCBM".  Substitute the call letters of your local or favorite radio station.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for responding. can you please tell me the response json for radio skill. for example i used for the audioPlayer ```const enqueueToken = val+1;const playBehavior = 'ENQUEUE'; const podcast = constants.audioData[val+1];const expectedPreviousToken = val; const offsetInMilliseconds = 0;``` like this.

Answer (score 1):

the radio skill will be implemented using AudioPlayer interface, please find more information on the link below:

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/audioplayer-interface-reference.html .

There is an AudioPlayer sample skill which actually streams from a radio station already to which you can refer. That can be found here:
https://github.com/alexa-samples/skill-sample-nodejs-audio-player

You will need to change the url stream and add your own. Please take into account that the URL you provide in the audioItem.stream.url property must meet these requirements:

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/audioplayer-interface-reference.html#audio-stream-requirements